# Off screen window

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

So I'm trying to implement an algorithm which is going to run a few simulations, and at the end I'm trying to show the 3D model in a window in tkinter (apart from blender). Therefore I'm using pyglet (extracting with PyWaveFront) to render the model, but some problems came up. What I'm asking is: Is there any possibility to use the 3d view render from blender, like off screen (No need to open blender)? Or just open blender's bordless window without showing the properties tab (File,Render,Window,Help...). If this doesn't make any sense let me know!Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can't open Blender without the windows window borders, but you can have the 3D view full screen.

[image]

(The following shortcuts are hyperlinks.)

1. Press [<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.ops.screen.html?highlight=screen.screen_full_area#bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area) to enter full area / presentation mode.
2. Press [<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm.window_fullscreen_toggle#bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle) to toggle full screen mode.

UI changes can be saved to a file and get set when the file is opened.

Comment: Thank you so much that is exacly what I was looking for!! Just another question if I may, is possible to run a script without being in the blender's text editor? Like importing the library into another IDE and run the script?

Comment: @FranciscoSerrano If you're looking for a better IDE, try Jaque Luckes "Autocomplete" Addon im combination with *Jedi*. Otherwise feel free to open a new question.